# list.layout.target is null

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4

I have a function in my view, which I am calling from 2 diff places, this is my func:

```
        protected function change():void
        {

            var g:GroupBase = productSetList.layout.target;
            if(g){
                trace('not null');
            }else{
                trace ('null');
            }

        }
```

I have s:List with the property `change="{change()}"` , so this is fine, the g never is null, but when I call from another function, the g is null why?!?!?!

***EDIT**

here is my spark list:

```
<s:List 
    id="productSetList" 
    dataProvider="{ model.productSets }" 
    change="{change()}"
    height="100%" width="100%"
    borderVisible="false" 
    itemRenderer="SideBarItemRenderer" top="20" left="15">
    <s:layout>
        <layout:VerticalWheelLayout gap="24"/>  
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Comment: what is productSetList.layout.target?

Answer (score 0):

This example calls the change() method from within the change handler and from the Button click handler and both seem to work fine:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.supportClasses.GroupBase;
            protected function change():void {
                var g:GroupBase = productSetList.layout.target;
                if(g){
                    trace('not null');
                }else{
                    trace ('null');
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button label="call" click="change()" />
    </s:controlBarContent>

    <s:List 
        id="productSetList" 
        change="{change()}"
        height="100%" width="100%"
        borderVisible="false" top="20" left="15">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>one</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="24"/>  
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

It might have something to do with your custom layout.  If you exchange that for an s:VerticalLayout does it work as you are expecting?  If not can you provide the source code for VerticalWheelLayout?